# How to use Bootstrap Navbar in Angular

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, navbar, bootstrap-4

I am using the navbar example in bootstrap in my Angular app but the nav bar doesn't come up at all.

Here is the navbar html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have installed bootstrap `npm install bootstrap --save`

and in styles.css imported bootstrap `@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';`

Please help Thanks

Comment: add     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
in index.html

Comment: Do you have a .angular-cli.json file? If so you can put in "styles": [
"styles.css", "../node_modules/bootstrap/dest/css/bootstrap.min.css"
]
This should add bootstrap functionality in your angular project if you have npm install bootstrap already

Comment: @MikeWight i added it nothing happens

Comment: @Akram it works but why doesnt it work the angular way if i add it to styles.css or angular.cli.json file any comments

Comment: Did you shut down your command control+c then restart ng serve?

Comment: Did that too @Akrams answers works but why ?

Comment: Because index.html is your master page in Angular (Or only page). So any stylesheet applied here should technically be available to your whole project. I'm not sure why the other way is not working. Must be something new with Bootstrap 4 maybe.

Comment: @INFOSYS, yes maybe new things in Angular2/4, so     try this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/> in index.html with all file must added it will be work

Comment: yes it works like this but strange it dosnt worjk the other way round please post an answer will mrk it correct

Comment: @INFOSYS, i add my response INFOSYS, sorry for late answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this 
-> install bootstrap by npm install --save bootstrap
-> in .angular-cli.json in styles add `"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",` will be like this

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

or add

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng2-bootstrap/x.x.x/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or via path `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/‌​>`

Hope useful for you

Answer (score -1):

There is no mention of Angular versions, but shouldn't this be as simple as adding the bootstrap import to the app-components.ts or what ever component typescript file is involved? The three bootstrap related lines below.

And I believe this was done for me via ng add angular-bootstrap-md

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```